# Make the width of a windows form to 100% as in HTML

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form which client needs to appear full screen in any resolution(Needs to looks like a web page).But the problem is to make the form width to 100%.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're never going to make a Windows application look like a web page. And any design that comes out of this endeavor will be hopelessly flawed and visually abhorrent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `FormWindowState` to maximize the form at loading.

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to set the width to 100%:

```cs
this.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
```

If you want set both width and height:

```cs
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

If you dont want this to do programmatically, you can also right click on the form to see the properties of that form and set "**WindowState**" property to "**Maximized**".

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In my application its a user control rather than a windows form.There it does not have a "WindowState" property

Answer (score 0):

> In my application its a user control rather than a windows form.

So manually set the size of the user control to the size of the containing form's client area.

Something like:

```
Control container = this.Parent;
if (container)
{
    // Fill the parent control.
    this.Size = container.ClientSize;
}
```

Or, better yet, set the user control's [`Dock` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) to `DockStyle.Fill` to handle this automatically:

```
this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```